# Add All Clicks to One Document not each Have its own Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I run this code I get feedback that A click has been added to the database, which is good. The problem is every time I click it creates a separate document for each click. Ultimately I want each clicks to be in the same document under a collection. What do I need to put in my code or what do I need to run in the terminal. Thanks.

```js
console.log('Server-side code running');

const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const app = express();


app.use(express.static('public'));


let db;


const url =  'mongodb://localhost:27017/clicks';

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, database) => {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  db = database;
  // start the express web server listening on 8080
  app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on 8080');
  });
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
  const click = {clickTime: new Date()};
  console.log(click);
  console.log(db);

  db.collection('clicks').save(click, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('click added to db');
    res.sendStatus(201);
  });
});


app.get('/clicks', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('clicks').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you're showing enough code. I see the `post` route which creates a click object, but I don't know how you're adding this to the database. Please show your code that actually adds the click object to your Mongo database

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I changed it to include the rest of the code. Must of accidentally not included some.

Comment: So.. you have a collection to hold only one document to hold all the clicks?

Comment: Yes I have a collection but every time I click it creates a separate document I the clicks into one document.

Comment: @Skylar-Osborne - does my answer below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs:

> `db.collection.save()` Updates an existing document or inserts a new document, depending on its document parameter.

Later, it specifies:

> If the document does not contain an `_id` field, then the `save()` method calls the `insert()` method. During the operation, the mongo shell will create an ObjectId and assign it to the _id field.

However,

> If the document contains an `_id` field, then the `save()` method is equivalent to an `update` with the upsert option set to true and the query predicate on the _id field.

Therefore, you should find the document's `_id`, and add it to the `click` object you are trying to `save` here:

```
app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
  const click = {
    clickTime: new Date(),
    _id: // TODO: Find _id property from database, insert here!
  };
  ...
});
```